# How to setup Scalelite load balanacer for BigBlueButton

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying out the BigBlueButton web conferencing system and would like to say it is amazing. So far I have set up a standalone BigBlueButton server with SSL and have configured Greenlight to work with it too. My moodle deployment also is integrated with BigBlueButton.

Now I am trying to scale out my BigBlueButton deployment by adding 3 or more BigBlueButton servers so I can handle more than 150 simultaneous users and for that purpose I have to setup Scalelite, the recommended load-balancer for BigBlueButton.

The part where I am confused is the setup of the PostgreSQL database and Redis cache as the docs aren't very clear about their setup. I am reaching out here so that someone who has some experience in setting up a Scalelite load-balancer can help me out.

Do the PostgreSQL and Redis need to be setup as Docker containers themselves? Furthermore, do they have to be on a system external to the Scaleleite server? If they do, how would the docker container for Scalelite connect with PostgreSQL and Redis when they are on an external system?

The link for the setup document is here: https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/scalelite

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I’m too in the middle of installing scalelite.

I decided to install postgres and redis on separate server, because i’m planning to have 2 scalelite server for HA.
Just normal install for postgres and redis, but you should be able to use docker as well.

You have to declare your redis and postgres server in `/etc/default/scalelite`.

```
REDIS_URL=redis://username:password@connection_url
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@connection_url
```